# Given that Γ ∪ {¬P} is unsatisfiable, show that Γ ⊨ Q → P?

Tags: logic

I honestly have no clue as to where to start with this question. My TA told us to think of it parts:

```
1) Consider what having a set unified with 'not P' means.
2) What this union being unsatisfiable would mean.
3) What this would mean for the relationship of 'if Q then P' with Gamma.
```

We barely touched this module yet so I don't know what to start off with.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that  **Γ ∪ {¬P}** is *unsatisfiable*, implies that **Γ ⊨ P**.

This is proved using the definition of the relation of *logical consequence* (  **⊨**) :

> every truth assignement (or *model*) that satisfy the formulae in **Γ** will also satisfy **P**.

To say that  **Γ ∪ {¬P}** is *unsatisfiable* means that there is **no** truth assignment that satisfy it; thus, every truth assignment that satisfy  **Γ** will not satisfy **¬P**, i.e. will necessarily satisfy **P**.

And this in turn means : **Γ ⊨ P**.

---

Now we apply the tuth table for the *conditional* (**→**) :

> **Q → P** is *true* either when **Q** is *false* or **P** is *true*.

Thus :

> every truth assignment that satisfy **P** will also satisfy **Q → P**,

and in conclusion :

> > every truth assignment that satisfy **Γ** will also satisfy **Q → P**,

i.e. :

> **Γ ⊨ Q → P**.

Comment: So to show Γ ⊨ Q → P, provide a truth table for Q → P when P = false?

Comment: But to show a set unsatisfiable, the consequent would have to be false wouldn't it?